# error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, npm

I do run program react-native to use code react-native run-android and npm start but program Error file AndroidManifest, if have a file.

error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
package.json

```
    {
  "name": "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn",
  "version": "2.0.4",
  "description": "InAppBrowser for React Native",
  "main": "index.js",
  "readmeFilename": "README.md",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    "start": "index.js",
  },
  "typings": "./index.d.ts",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser/issues"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react-native",
    "in",
    "app",
    "browser",
    "inappbrowser",
    "in-app-browser"
  ],
  "author": "Juan David Nicholls Cardona",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser",
  "license": "MIT",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react-native": ">=0.55.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native": "^0.59.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.80.0"
  }
}
```

up data

```
This error is caused by `hasteImpl` returning the same name for different files.
    at setModule (F:\react-hr-and-ess\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:569:17)
    at workerReply (F:\react-hr-and-ess\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:641:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:16876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUx1z.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcuq7.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. (in project directory) mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
2. react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
3. react-native run-android

add comma after `"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",`

delete  comma after `"start": "index.js"`

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "index.js"
  },
```

**Correct json**

```
    {
  "name": "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn",
  "version": "2.0.4",
  "description": "InAppBrowser for React Native",
  "main": "index.js",
  "readmeFilename": "README.md",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "index.js"
  },
  "typings": "./index.d.ts",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser/issues"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react-native",
    "in",
    "app",
    "browser",
    "inappbrowser",
    "in-app-browser"
  ],
  "author": "Juan David Nicholls Cardona",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser",
  "license": "MIT",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react-native": ">=0.55.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native": "^0.59.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.80.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: error JSON Error in F:\react-hr-and-ess\package.json:
Unexpected string in JSON at position 252 while parsing '{  "name": "react-native-inappbrowser-r'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details. , edit ?? thx

Comment: How do you use the --help command, what does it return? I update  my answer

Comment: I did not know, no my project

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this helped me too.  the entry point is the important for this solution ,if anyone is jr like me

this might help too. [enter link description here](https://proandroiddev.com/bundling-react-native-during-android-release-builds-ec52c24e200d)

My problem originated from after I installed  qs.js and stopped it in them middle of install from my git bash window (i was logged in as user from my $path, not explicitly Admin) 
I ended up doing  react-native-clean-project  as well , that did not help this specific problem

Not: Win 10, Android Emulator, React-Native-Debugger 0.10.1

Comment: ok i take that back it didnt work , having punt this and try it in expo